# Why can't I get the list of tables when connecting to oracle in SSIS?

Tags: oracle, ssis

When I connect to Oracle from SSIS through OLE DB, and try to locate the tables, I get a huge list. Why don't I get only the database tables?

My connection is:
Provider = Native OLE DB\Oracle Provider for OLE DB.
Server or file name = localhost:1521/orcl

[Reference image on the listing I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPiyD.png)

Comment: That appears to be a list of tables in the database so I'm not sure what your issue is.  Perhaps you could ask for a user that has been granted to a smaller subset of tables within the database.  Perhaps only those tables in a single schema?

Comment: @Justin cueva. The connection that I establish understanding that it points to a database with 8 tables only. However I get all that list and I don't understand why. Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that you're not using "database" the way Oracle uses "database".  It appears you mean that you are connecting as a user that owns a schema with 8 tables.  It appears that user also has access to many more tables in the database from other schemas.  You could ask for those additional privileges to be revoked.  Or you could ask for a user to be created that actually only has access to the 8 tables you are interested in.   Or you could just go down the list until you find the tables in the schema you are interested in.